# Sending a plotly graph over flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, ubuntu, flask, plotly

Right now I have a code that uses plotly to create a figure

```
def show_city_frequency(number_of_city = 10):
plot_1 = go.Histogram(
    x=dataset[dataset.city.isin(city_count[:number_of_city].index.values)]['city'],
    showlegend=False)

## Creating the grid for all the above plots
fig = tls.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)

fig.append_trace(plot_1,1,1)


fig['layout'].update(showlegend=True, title="Frequency of cities in the dataset ")
return plot(fig)
```

I want to incorporate this into a flask function and send it to an html template as a bytes io object using send_file.  I was able to do this for a matplotlib just using:

```
img = io.BytesIO()
plt.plot(x,y, label='Fees Paid')
plt.savefig(img, format='png')
img.seek(0)
return send_file(img,   mimetype='image/png')
```

I've read that I can do basically the same thing except using:

```
img =  plotly.io.to_image(fig, format='png')
img.seek(0)
return send_file(img, mimetype='image/png')
```

but I can't seem to find where to download plotly.io.  I've read that plotly offline doesn't work for Ubuntu so I am wondering if that is what my issue is as well.  I am also open to new suggestions of how to send this image dynamically to my html code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Plotly offline works fine with Ubuntu. If you want to serve Plotly graphs via Flask you would need to convert your data/graphs to JSON and then serve them. Have a look here: https://github.com/plotly/plotlyjs-flask-example